# Аналог php pack в python?

Tags: php, python

В **php** операцияя  `base64_encode(pack('n', 250)` равна **APo=**

В **python** `base64.b64encode(pack('<H',250))` равна **+gA=**

В питон использую **struct**. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порядок байтов надо поменять с '<' на '>'

```
base64.b64encode(pack('>H',250))
```